# Rename files incrementally in a specific directory?

Tags: scripts, gnome-terminal, command-line

I have a directory containing bunch of `.txt` files , I need a command to rename these files by one command ,  so their name will be : `file1.txt , file2.txt, file3.txt , etc .`

Any Help ?

Comment: do you mind if it is a python script?

Comment: the script should be executed in terminal , but you can write your script .

Comment: `for i in *.txt; do echo mv "$i" "file${i#file}"; done`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use this in terminal to rename files as you wished,

```bsh
j=1;for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" file"$j".txt; let j=j+1;done
```

It will do the job.

**Explanation:**

- Set a counter `j`, initially set it to 1
- Initiate a for loop and use a shell glob `*.txt` to obtain all `txt` files.
- for each file rename it using `mv` and increase the counter by 1.

Comment: can you explain your command ?

Comment: @nux see the edits and feel free to discuss if necessary.

Comment: ok thank you ,i will consider it as a right answer , i found a small script that satisfy my needs too .

Answer (score 8):

You can use the rename command, which is usually included in a default installation:

```
c=0 rename 's/.*/sprintf("file%05d.txt", ++$ENV{c})/e' *
```

Use the -n flag if you want to do a test first:

```
c=0 rename -n 's/.*/sprintf("file%05d.txt", ++$ENV{c})/e' *
```

The way this works is, for each argument, it executes the perl `s///` expression, and performs the rename from the original to the replaced string. In the replacement string I use `sprintf` to format the name, where I use the environment variable `c` as the counter from 1.

In most cases you also may need leading "0" for each number, `%05d` does the trick, where 5 is number of digits.

Comment: Great example, should be a top answer. With `%05d` instead of `%d` you can add leading `0` to the name, with 5 digits.

Answer (score 2):

The following command will also rename files incrementally :

```
cd (directory containing files )
```

Then run this script :

```
count=1
for i in *; do
    mv "${i}" file${count}.`echo "${i}" | awk -F. '{print $2}'`
    ((++count))

done
```